# Simulate Latency with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing an AJAX-heavy site with JavaScript MVC and an ASP.NET MVC server.  To test some of the client-side caching and get a better idea of where to put loading gif's and messages into the site I would like to artificially simulate some latency on the server.

I guess the easiest way would be to use a Global Action Filter and simply do a Thread.Sleep, but this won't work for when the client loads JavaScript files and other content.

I'm guessing I can do this with an HttpModule, but I'm note sure.

Any ideas?

Edit:  This is for testing on my local/development machine, using IIS Express

Comment: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" for modules section in system.server configuration would run all the modules for static resources also, so I would to this with an httpmodule (or in Global.asax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like most straightforward solution would be to leverage bandwidth throttling by reconfiguring IIS: [Enabling Bandwidth Throttling (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83d66f47-8184-4d25-afcf-c229fffdc981.mspx?mfr=true)

Also here is a trick to simulate a modem connection when using a Fiddler using the menu option

> Rules > Performance > Simulate Modem speeds

Comment: Ok, should have specified - I'm using IIS Express - this is for my development machine

Comment: I would suggest you to setup Fiddler, just wondering how it possible to work without it ;)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but I actually used the suggestion of going with Fiddler

Comment: I also preffer Fiddler rather then playing with IIS